# What was the first science-fictional depiction of orbital directed-energy weapon platforms?

Tags: history-of

In the late 1980s I came across many representations of orbital directed-energy weapons.
In 1987-1988 alone there were the "Finger of God" weapons in Vinge's "[True Names](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?14225)"
(1981, but read in [*True Names ... and other Dangers*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?36909) 1987), the laser satellites in
Bova's "[Battle Station](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?540685)" (1988, in the [eponymous collection](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2)) and SOL in [*Akira*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akira_(1988_film)).

[This previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169472/which-sci-fi-work-introduced-the-idea-of-satellite-based-weapons) seemed to want to ask about orbital beam weapons, but accepted as an
answer one that showed nuclear-armed missiles being stored in orbit.

I'm wondering what was the first work to depict orbital directed-energy weapons?

- not spaceships capable of moving beyond orbit or re-entering
- not platforms for dropping bombs or missiles stored in orbit
- not kinetic weapons (a.k.a. "rods from God")

Comment: Can't put this as an answer as no source other than memory, but I recall something that may count in the Lensman series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you count orbiting weapons that just concentrate the sun's energy using mirrors/lenses (like using a magnifying glass to burn ants), there's a 1927 example mentioned on p. 260 of the article ["The Historical Death Ray and Science Fiction in the 1920s and 1930s"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25746409):

> The 1927 German novel *Flammen aus dem Weltraum* [Flames from Space] by Karl August von Laffert describes a space station mounted with huge reflectors that act as a sun gun, anticipating, or perhaps inspiring, the actual secret German project at Hillersleben mentioned previously.

Searching a little for this title, I think the article misprinted the name, it should be [*Flammen aus dem Weltenraum*](https://www.abebooks.com/Flammen-Weltenraum-Zukunfts-Roman-Laffert-Karl-August-1872-1938/22407161727/bd). And as for the "actual secret German project" they mention, see [here](https://io9.gizmodo.com/how-germany-planned-to-fry-the-world-462891057) and [here](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/planetaryattack.php#sonnengewehr) for more details.

The [Project Rho page on "Orbital Planetary Attack"](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/planetaryattack.php) includes [this section](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/planetaryattack.php#id--Orbital_Bombardment--Burning_Glass) which gives plenty of other examples of stories involving this type of weapon from the early 20th century, though none earlier than 1927.